# Dynamic array or resize extend?

Tags: progress-4gl

This is a superfluous question. Is there any dynamic array or list in Progress 10.2B?

Example:

I create a base class called "InventoryTransaction". I read a MSSQL table from Progress and I would like to create an instance of InventoryTransaction class for each record found then add it to a "list/array" so I can later process them.

Is there something like MyArray:Add(MyItem) that will increase automatically the array size +1 then will add the instance of MyItem to the array?

I discovered the function EXTENT to set a size dynamically to an array but I do not know the count before reading all the transaction in the MSSQL table. Alternatively, I could execute a "select count(*) from MyTable" before reading all the transaction to retrieve the count and then extent the array.

Thank you!
Happy friday!
Sebastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - no, the 10.2B AVM doesn't allow you to dynamically resize an array.

The long answer is you could (a) add the object to a linked list of objects, or (b) create a temp-table with a Progress.Lang.Object field, create a new TT record for each object instance you want to track, and assign the object's pointer to the TT's PLO field.

Comment: I like the linked list object approach. I think I will create a base class with previous, next, add and remove method. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can create "indeterminate" arrays.  i.e.

```
define variable x as decimal extent no-undo.
```

An indeterminate array variable can be in one of two states: fixed or unfixed, meaning it either has a fixed dimension or it does not. An indeterminate array variable has an unfixed dimension when first defined. You can fix the dimension of an indeterminate array variable by:

- Initializing the array values when you define the variable,
- Using the INITIAL option
- Setting the number of elements in the array variable
- Using the EXTENT statement
- Assigning a determinate array to the indeterminate array, fixing it to the dimension of the determinate array
- Passing array parameters to a procedure, user-defined function, or class-based method, so that the indeterminate array variable is the target for the passing of a determinate array, fixing the indeterminate array to the dimension of the determinate array

Once fixed, ABL treats a fixed indeterminate array as a determinate array.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your feedbacks! This is the approach that have been used for now. It is just we do not know how many item in advance.

Comment: Tim's TT approach makes a lot of sense in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered progress.lang.object:

**FILE: array.p**

```
/* declaration */
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE arrITem
    FIELD Item AS CLASS PROGRESS.lang.OBJECT.

DEFINE VARIABLE oItem AS CLASS Item NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

/* create 10 products */

DO i = 1 TO 10:
    CREATE arrItem.
    arrItem.Item = NEW Item("Item_" + STRING(i), "Description_" + STRING(i)).
END.

/* display object information */
FOR EACH arrItem:
    ASSIGN oItem = CAST(arrItem.Item,Item).
    DISPLAY oItem:ItemNo.
END.
```

**FILE: item.cls**

```
CLASS Item:


    DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY ItemNo AS CHARACTER
        GET.
        SET.

    DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY DESCRIPTION AS CHARACTER
        GET.
        SET.

    /* constructor */  
    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Item():
    END.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Item(
        INPUT strItemNo AS CHARACTER
       ,INPUT strDescription AS CHARACTER
        ):

        ASSIGN ItemNo = strItemNo.
        ASSIGN DESCRIPTION = strDescription.
    END.

END CLASS.
```

Thank you!
Sebastien